# django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug-toolbar'

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I just tried to install the django-debug-toolbar. I believe I followed all the steps as indicated in the docs. I am using docker, so I included the following in my settings:

```
if os.environ.get('DEBUG'):
    import socket
    hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    INTERNAL_IPS = [ip[: ip.rfind(".")] + ".1" for ip in ips] + ["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.2"]
```

After installing, I ran `docker-compose build` then `docker-compose up -d`. `docker-compose logs` and `docker-compose exec web python manage.py collectstatic` show the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug-toolbar'
```

The only thing I think I did differently from the docs is that I use pipenv. I exited docker-compose and then installed via `pipenv install django-debug-toolbar`. Debug toolbar is in my `pipfile`.

I'm never sure if I'm supposed to exit docker-compose before install a module via pipenv (or if it matters). I also tried installed via `docker-compose exec web pipenv install django-debug-toolbar`, shut down the container, then `docker-compose up -d --build` but the module not found error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Typo error on my part.  In settings.py under installed apps I had `debug-toolbar` instead of `debug_toolbar`.

Comment: 2 hours until I see this... TX for followup!